# how to refine the mesh in some parts of 3D-Model?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have created a 3D model. I want to refine the mesh at some parts (like the picture shows) of 3D model. I want to increase the number of meshes in the red circle area. Waht should I do? Thanks a lot.[image]

Comment: Change to Sculpt mode and sculpt the changes?

Comment: Do you mean you want to refine the shapes and forms, as in sculpting more detail? Do you mean refine the topology of the existing mesh? If you mean refine the topology, then I would suggest looking at different techniques in retopology, where we turn on snapping and draw a new mesh on the surface of the old mesh, making more logical edge flow.

Comment: I want to increase the number of meshes in the red circle. What should I do?

Comment: This might be helpful https://youtu.be/IG1IEpU5VAw?t=794